# WEKA J48 decision tree with non linearly separable data

Tags: weka, decision-tree, j48, c4.5

Does Weka J48 Decision Tree classifier support classification for a problem with intrinsically non linearly separable data? In short, is J48 either a linear or a non linear classifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In short, is J48 either a linear or a non linear classifier?

- I don't know.

However, the decision boundaries of J48 can be made, in a way, "stepwise linear".  So you can approximate a nonlinear decision boundary if you set minNumObjects low enough and set pruning to false (= unpruned to true).

Here is a visualization of the linear boundaries using weka's BoundaryVisualizer:

[image]

This is accessible via the small rectangular "Weka GUI Chooser" window.
There you can load your own dataset.

Here is a video that explains it with more details: https://youtu.be/fMxfUKYkcVg?t=568